# How to auto-copy a specific cells down with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to auto copy selected cell values down one by one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFGdo.jpg)

the code i used is

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

but unlikely that code copies all row values, I need only those 4 cells.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve. In your screenshot we cannot see row numbers or column headers. Please edit your question and post the code you have so far. Add a mockup of the desired results and explain in context.

Comment: Can you post the VBA code that you tried?

Comment: Your question is quit confusing,, please edit the post & add the VBA code you have tried so far also the expected output !!

Comment: Post Edited, Is it clear now?

Comment: `Selection.Offset(1, 0).FillDown` copies the selected cells to the row below the selected cells. Is that part of what you need?

Comment: it copies all row that's not my request :(

Comment: It copies the selection. The selection can be an entire row or it can be a few cells. Or try this code: `ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Offset(1, 0).FillDown` changes the range from one active cell, to one row and four columns, to one row below, and then fills down from the row above.